# Match everything inside a "method call" string with possibly nested parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to write a python regex to replace the string `FARM_FINGERPRINT()` and anything inside that method call with the string '0'. For example, for the string:

```
s = 'FARM_FINGERPRINT(stuff(more stuff()), even more stuff), another_thing()'
```

The regex should replace it with `'0, another_thing()'`.

I'd be open to non-regex solutions as well.

Comment: It won't be possible to handle nested `()` with a RegEx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identify the start of the string you intend to match and the first parenthesis in that match (thus initializing `p_count` as `1`). Iterate through the string character by character and add `1` to `p_count` for every open parenthesis `(` and subtract `1` from `p_count` for every closed parenthesis `)`. Exit the loop when all open parenthesis have been closed.

```
s = 'FARM_FINGERPRINT(stuff(more stuff()), even more stuff), another_thing()'

start = 'FARM_FINGERPRINT('

p_count = 1
for idx, i in enumerate(s.split('FARM_FINGERPRINT(')[-1]):
    if i=='(': p_count+=1
    elif i==')': p_count-=1
    elif p_count==0: stop = idx; break

string_to_replace = s[:len(start)+stop]

s = s.replace(string_to_replace, '0')

print(s)
```

Output:

```
0, another_thing()
```

Comment: I figured it was something like this. Thanks!